# Spring - environment variable - storing in XML and accessing in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, spring

I there easy way, how to store variable in XML spring files with something like this:

```
<systemvariable name="hocuspocus" value="it is working" />
```

and then access them in Java service/controller layer with something like this?

```
System.getProperty("hocuspocus");
```

I do not want stored/read .properties file, just one variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a system property by including the following bean:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="staticMethod" value="java.lang.System.setProperty"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>hocuspocus</value>
            <value>valueForHocusPocus</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And later read it with:

```
System.getProperty("hocuspocus");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just inject it into your controller/service.

```
<bean id="myService" class="my.company.MyService">
    <property name="myProperty" value="blah"/>
</bean>
```

with

```
private String myProperty;
```

in your service/controller.